# why my javascript code dosen't work(about search and filter bar)

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>a1</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="a1.css" />
   <script src="a1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form id = "gallary" method="get" action="">
<div id="searchBox">
  <input type="text" id="searchBar" placeholder="Search titles" />
<input type="submit" id="searchBtn" value="search" onclick="searchFunction()"/>

  <select name="genre" id ="filterBar">
    <option>Genre</option> 
    <option>Baroque</option>
    <option>Mannerism</option>
    <option>Neo-classicism</option>
    <option>Realisim</option>
    <option>Romanticism</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" id = "filterBtn" value="filter" onclick = 
"filterFunction()"  />
</div>
</form>
<div id="artistBox">
  <table>
    <caption>Paintings</caption>

    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Artist</th>
        <th>Year</th>
        <th>Genre</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody id="tbody">
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="paintingname" /><img 
src="05030.jpg"/></td>
        <td>Death of Marat</td>
        <td>David, Jacques-Louis</td>
        <td>1793</td>
        <td>Romanticism</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="paintingname" /><img 
src="120010.jpg"/></td>
        <td>Potrait of Eleanor of Toledo</td>
        <td>Bronzino, Agnolo</td>
        <td>1545</td>
        <td>Mannerism</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="paintingname" /><img 
src="07020.jpg"/></td>
        <td>Liberty leading the people</td>
        <td>Delacroix, Eugene</td>
        <td>1830</td>
        <td>Romanticism</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="paintingname" /><img 
src="13030.jpg"/></td>
        <td>Arrangement in Grey and Black</td>
        <td>Whistler, James Abbott</td>
        <td>1871</td>
        <td>Realisim</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="paintingname" /><img 
src="06010.jpg"/></td>
        <td>Mademoiselle Caroline Riviere</td>
        <td>Ingres, Jean-Auguste</td>
        <td>1806</td>
        <td>Neo-classicism</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>


  </table>

</div>   
</body>
</html>

enter code here
```

above is my HTML code.
the searchBar is for searcing titles(the second column of tbody), the filter is for filtering genres(the fourth column of tbody).

I want to search and filter some specific content form the table and use on-click to trigger my functions but it didn't work. Can anyone help me?

```
var input = document.getElementById("searchBar").value.toUpperCase();
var tbody = document.getElementById("tbody");
var tr = tbody.getElementByTagName("tr");
var td;

var filter = document.getElementById("filterBar").value;

function makeGreen(inputDiv){
    inputDiv.style.backgroundColor = "green";
}

function searchFunction(){

    for (var i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        td = tr[i].getElementByTagName("td")[1];
        if(td.innerHTML.toUpperCase() == input){
            makeGreen(tr[i]);
        }
    };
}
function filterFunction(){
for (var i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementByTagName("td")[4];
    if(td.innerHTML == input){
        tr[i].style.display = "";
    }else{
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
    }
 }
```

[image]

Comment: You dropped the 's' in `getElementsByTagName()`. Correct this and, if it doesn't work, send the HTML so that we can correct any further errors.

Comment: thanks! I corrected the get ElementsByTagName(),however it still didn't work at all.

Comment: I have already sent my HTML code on the question.

Comment: "it didn't work" isn't a very helpful problem statement. Have you checked the developer console (normally activated using your F12 key)? If so, what does it show?

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the values of 'input', 'tbody','tr', and 'td' at the start of the script.  These get evaluated when the script is loaded but destroyed when the the script file is finished loading.  That is the "searchFunction" does not know about the values of these tags.

Consider the updated code: (see it in action at: [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/gqpJ0TfYsOEJ1v3Ez2qz?p=preview))

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function makeGreen(inputDiv){
      inputDiv.style.backgroundColor = "green";
  }

  function searchFunction(){
      var input = document.getElementById("searchBar").value.toUpperCase();
      var input = document.getElementById("searchBar").value.toUpperCase();
      var tbody = document.getElementById("tbody");
      var tr = tbody.getElementsByTagName("tr");
      console.log(input);
      for (var i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
          td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
          var filter = document.getElementById("filterBar").value;

          if(td.innerHTML.toUpperCase() == input){
              makeGreen(tr[i]);
          }
      };
  }
  function filterFunction(){
    var input = document.getElementById("searchBar").value.toUpperCase();
    var tbody = document.getElementById("tbody");
          var tr = tbody.getElementsByTagName("tr");
      for (var i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
      td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[4];
      if(td.innerHTML == input){
          tr[i].style.display = "";
      }else{
          tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    } // <-- Missing
 }
</script>
```

Comment: thank you! It works now. However, it just show the result a flash of time when the search match. Do you know how can I make the search result maintain until I refresh the page?

Comment: Change the input type=button instead of submit.  Check the updated Plunker.

Comment: I also have found this bug.Anyway,thank you so much!

Comment: It's not a bug.  It's expected behavior